# javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException on Websphere

Tags: jsf, websphere, cdi

We have an application developed in JSF and we are converting it to use CDI. During this process we made tests in Wildfly and we were able to have it up and running as it was before the conversion.
Problems came up when we deployed it on Websphere!

Our app has two parts, for simplicity Part 1 and Part 2, where the resulting jar from Part 1 is included in Part 2, meaning that the war file deployed in Websphere already contains the jar file from Part 1.

Now, when the app starts up in Websphere the following error is thrown

```
[4/28/17 16:35:54:107 CEST] 00000083 BeansDeployer E BeansDeployer deploy 
                                 javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [web.frmwrk.mgbean.WebSession] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into 
 Field Injection Point, field :  protected web.frmwrk.mgbean.WebSession web.frmwrk.FacesBean.ws, Bean Owner : [-2102135427,Name:dealerLink,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[web.mgbean.dealer.Link,web.frmwrk.FacesBean,java.lang.Object,java.io.Serializable],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.inject.Named]]
     InjectionType   :  [class web.frmwrk.mgbean.WebSession]
     Annotated       :  [Annotated Field,Base Type : class web.frmwrk.mgbean.WebSession,Type Closures : [class web.frmwrk.mgbean.WebSession, class web.frmwrk.FacesBean, class java.lang.Object, interface java.io.Serializable],Annotations : [@javax.inject.Inject()],Java Member Name : ws]
     Qualifiers      :  [[@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]]
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtils.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtils.java:92)
```

We have searched for a possible solution, but no luck so far. During our search we found this [page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014823319). We did add a Class-Path on MANIFEST.MF mentioning Part 1, but nothing changed.

Did any of you face a similar problem? Is there any special configuration we may need to do on Websphere to make this work as it is on Wildfly?

Comment: Wildfly Weld (CDI reference implementation). Whereas Websphere used to use an alternative implementation - OpenWebBeans (latest versions are using Weld as well). There are quite a few known differences in those two and you might have bumped into some. I don't know much about OWB, but too see what's going on, please post your deployment structure as it is. Especially if we are talking EAR, or shared libs etc... Those are areas in which those impls often differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you used a different CDI or EE spec level in Wildfly.

You didn't specify any versions nor what class is supposed to satisfy that dependency nor where it's stored.  But you likely need a beans.xml in the jar containing the class meant to satisfy that dependency.

Comment: I don't think this is the usual "`beans.xml` blindshot" thing. It looks like it's caused by the differences between Weld and OWB. If it worked without beans.xml on one AS, it has to work on the other, that much the specification says.

Comment: Seems likely enough for me, given that 1 AS is known to be on CDI 1.0.

Comment: Indeed, even though we are using JEE7, OWB still needs to have bean.xml. Thank you very much.